# Regex: replace all with '' except lowercase

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string, e.g. `/test/` and I'd like to mantain only the lowercase.
How can I do it with `preg_replace`?

```
$string = '/test/';
$new_string = preg_replace('?????', '', $string);
$new_string = 'test';
```

Comment: what you want to do because I don't understand. You want remove `/`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simpler than you think:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: `^` inside the `[]` means all characters except those inside the brackets? And the `/g`? It returns me this error: `Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'g' in ...`

Comment: @Perocat There is no `g` modifier in PHP. In JavaScript it means "match all".

Comment: Ok, so in PHP the "match all" is automatic? Without `/g`, it matches all and not only the first?

Comment: @Perocat "match all" doesn't make sense while replacing. But when you're using `preg_match` it will match only the first instance, so instead of using the `g` modifier, you use `preg_match_all` which is equivalent to it.